# Bounding distance between intersection point and minimizer of 2 monotonic functions

Tags: real-analysis

Given a non decreasing $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$, and a non increasing function $g:[0,1]\to\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ that intersect at $x^\perp$. And given $x^* = \operatorname{arg}\min_{0\leq x \leq 1}\{f(x)+g(x)\}$, can we bound $|x^\perp-x^*|$ ? What additional assumption would help bound the distance?

Comment: What does non-increasing(decreasing) on a closed interval mean?

Comment: @Croissant For non-decreasing $f$, it means $\forall x,y \in [0,1], x\leq y \iff f(x) \leq f(y)$. Same with sign reversed for non-increasing.